# Webpack is importing CSS of other bundles

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader, webpack-style-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have a Webpack setting to build different bundles and put all the CSS used by the bundle in a CSS file.

The problem is that Webpack is putting all the CSS of all the bundles together.

Mi project is configured in the following way.

*webpack.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'bundle-a': './src/bundle-a.ts',
    'bundle-b': './src/bundle-b.ts'
  },
  ...
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['ts-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: 'local'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

*src/bundle-a.ts*

```js
import style from './bundle-a.css';

...
```

*src/bundle-a.css*

```css
.class-bundle-a {
  ...
}
```

*src/bundle-b.js*

```js
import style from './bundle-b.css';

...
```

*src/bundle-b.css*

```css
.class-bundle-b {
  ...
}
```

When I build the project I get the following CSS files.

*dist/bundle-a.css*

```css
.class-bundle-a {
  ...
}

.class-bundle-b {
  ...
}
```

*dist/bundle-b.css*

```css
.class-bundle-a {
  ...
}

.class-bundle-b {
  ...
}
```

I expect that the `dist/bundle-a.css` only have the CSS imported in the `src/bundle-a.ts`, but also I am getting the CSS imported by the `src/bundle-b.ts`, and the same pass with the `src/bundle-b.css`. The same happens if I use **style-loader**.

I want to know if this is the expected behavior or I have some error in my code.

Comment: what is your version of webpack? try extracting css with `extract-text-webpack-plugin`

Comment: My version of webpack is the `5.10.1`.

Comment: Can you share project (with all settings) via git?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [postcss](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/) loader with the [cssnano](https://cssnano.co/) too.

The objective of that is to optimize your css files import.

One of the cssnano optimizations is to discard duplicates [cssnano#discardDuplicates](https://cssnano.co/docs/optimisations/discardduplicates)

You can try using like this in your webpack.config.js:

```
...
rules: [
  ...
  {
    test: /\.css$/i,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        options: {
          publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/css/')
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {importLoaders: 1},
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          postcssOptions: {
            config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js'),
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  ...
```

And create a file for your postcss ( postcss.config.js ) like this:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'cssnano': {
      autoprefixer: { add: true },
      discardComments: { removeAll: true },
      discardDuplicates: true,
      discardEmpty: true,
      discardOverridden: true,
      discardUnused: true,
      reduceIdents: false,
      reduceInitial: false,
      reduceTransforms: false,
      zindex: false
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional rule. It's a bit redundant but works for me:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'bundle-a': './src/bundle-a.ts',
        'bundle-b': './src/bundle-b.ts'
    },
    // ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            // ...
            {
                test: /bundle-a\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /bundle-b\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            // ..
        ]
    },
    optimization: { 
        // ...
    },
    plugins: [
        // ...
    ]
};
```